# How can i read yaml file from a directory without mentioning the exact directory?

Tags: go

```
package gateway

import (
    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)
type ConfigRemote struct {
    Drkeyparams DrKeyParams
    MqttRemote  MqttRemote
    CoapRemote  CoapRemote
}

func GetConfig() Config {
    var conf Config
    reader, _ := os.Open("/home/pi/go/src/github.com/vishnumohan1993/scioniotgateway/gateway/home.yaml")
    buf, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
    yaml.Unmarshal(buf, &conf)
    return conf
}
```

I tried to put `./home.yaml` and simply `home.yaml...` but is not working. Kindly assist

Comment: How do you name something without naming something? Figure out this puzzle, and you will have your answer.

Comment: Is it some static file you want to deliver along with your program?

Comment: Have you tried `ioutil.ReadFile("home.yaml")` ?

Comment: Please note that a process runing on a (modern commodity OS) can have its "current working directory" set to virtually anything—unless specifically arranged to be otherwise by the code which creates it. So the problem you have to sort out for yourself _first_ is to think through how your program will be deployed and run, and then think through the way to tell the running process how it should find its configuration. You might start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64241384/720999).

Comment: …and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/f6aini/api_made_with_go_is_a_systemd_service_the_best/fi6gydj/).

Comment: @bereal

Yes its a static file

Comment: @VishnuMohan then you may want to consider any of the few file embedding libraries, such as [https://github.com/markbates/pkger](https://github.com/markbates/pkger). There's a large list [here](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/draft-embed.md#background).

Answer (score 0):

Make the path (absolute or relative) a command line option.

Answer (score -2):

```
dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path.Join(dir, `./home.yaml`))
```

You can put the config file under the top level of your project folder, then make sure the program's output file will write into this folder also, then it can read this file using relative path.

Note: the relative path determine by the go output binary file's location.

Comment: Relying on the contents of the 1st argument passed by the OS is error-prone on Unices: 1) one can start a process using weird stuff like `../dir_symlink/../image_name`; 2) both the parent process (the one who spawned the process we're talking about) and the process itself can change that value (e.g. [even `bash` can do that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562449/43156)). A better approach is [`os.Executable`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Executable) but even better approach is to make the program have a direct and reliable way to get the full pathname of its configuration file.

Comment: The absolute path can works in any case.
But I just use it in a simple way, build the program and put the config file beside the binary file, it works for me, different scenario could have different solution.